# Xml Selecting New Element

Tags: c#, xml, xna

I need to be able to return the data from the select block. How would I do this?

```
public double loadData()
    {
        XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load("XMLFILE1.xml");
        var data = from query in loadedData.Descendants("ScoreData")
                   select new Score
                   {
                      HighScore = (Double)query.Element("HS"),
                   };

        return highScore;
    }
```

Comment: Im trying to select out of my xml file. Its xna c#. @StefanDenchev

Comment: What isn't working? `loadData(out data)` what you want?

Comment: I am very new to using xml files and doing what i did above. Is that what would be able to retrieve the values set by what was done in the select new score part? If so thats what I need. I need to return the value set.

Comment: linq to xml isn't my forte..

Comment: Is there any way you know of that could read the contents of my xml file and return the score value set in there? @StefanDenchev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a single value  then why are you creating a `Score` instance?

This will return the `First` score value:

```
return (from query in loadedData.Descendants("ScoreData")
               select  (Double)query.Element("HS")).First();
```

This will return the `Maximum` score value:

```
return (from query in loadedData.Descendants("ScoreData")
               select  (Double)query.Element("HS")).Max();
```

If you need to get all scores you should change return type to `double[]`

```
public double[] loadData()
{
    XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load("XMLFILE1.xml");

    return (from query in loadedData.Descendants("ScoreData")
                 select (Double)query.Element("HS")).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: When I reboot the emulator my save is lost. Why is this? @Selman22